# Razor does not see the GetEnumerator() method from Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

using this class:

```
public class Account{

.....

   public Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<PaymentSchedule> PaymentSchedules { get; private set; }

.....
}
```

in this razor view (razor 1.0,in MVC3):

```
@model AccountSummaryViewModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/SiteLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@Model.Child.Name's Account Summary</h2>
//code ommited
 @foreach(var schedule in Model.Child.Account.PaymentSchedules) {
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>@schedule.NextRun.ToShortDateString()</td>
                <td>@schedule.Interval</td>
                <td>@schedule.Description</td>
                <td class="money">@schedule.Amount.ToString("c")</td>
                @if(Model.IsParentView) {
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "RemoveSchedule", "Schedule", new { id = Model.Child.Id, scheduleId = schedule.Id }, new { @class = "warning" })</td>
                }else{
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                }
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

gives me the following error:

> Error 1   foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet'
>   because
>   'Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet'
>   does not contain a public definition for
>   'GetEnumerator'   e:\Interviu\Suteki.TardisBank\Suteki.TardisBank\Views\Account\Summary.cshtml    25  6   Suteki.TardisBank

In the web.config inside the View folder, i have added the Iesi namespaces, but that doesn't help. What can I do next?

Comment: could you see if this `Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet` inherits from `ICollection` or `IEnumerable`?

Comment: It does inherit both the IEnumerable interfaces. After changing the collection to a System.Collection.Generic.ISet, it worked! I am pretty Razor doesn't "see" the Iesi assembly/namespace, even after adding it in the ~/Views webconfig.

Comment: Glad it worked :) although I would say that MVC **does** see that namespace since it just said that it doesnt contain a getenumerator.